# Magento Layered Navigation Sort

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I'm wondering if it's possible to move the way the categories are listed in the layered navigation... In the admin, there is a category that's at the bottom of a root category but on the front end shows at the top of the layered navigation.

Is there away I can move these around?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to distinct between the **Category Navigation block** and **the Layered Navigation block** !

**Category Navigation** : displays categories, subcategories with their products with certain conditions like : visible, active, assigned in a category etc ...

**Layered Navigation** : is a block filter navigation which allows you to filter the products. All these filters are dinamic and depend directly on products in current category.

For more [information](https://www.manadev.com/documentation/magento-1.x-guides/general/what-is-layered-navigation-in-magento).

Comment: Hi Prince, it looks like it Category Navigation block, is it possible?